# Need suggestion on choosing keypoints based on neighbourhood density

Tags: statistics, cluster-analysis, distribution

I have a grey-scale image . 
I get SIFT keypoints . 
I can define density of each SIFT keypoint based on number of SIFT keypoints found in neighbourhood of radius 'r' . 
My dilemma is that how can I decide threshold of density automatically for any image ?
I have considered an option of choosing top 50 most dense keypoints but that is very naive .
I am looking for some parameter related to distribution that does not change much if few SIFT keypoints are removed .
 
Any suggestion on automatically choosing 'r' would be also welcome.
Thanks.

PS:My final aim is to treat relative arrangement of neaby dense SIFT keypoints as an indentifier of the object .

Comment: Are you sure that SIFT density is meaningful? I thought the best keypoints are solitary ones, that may arise at building corners in architecture images etc.?

Comment: ok . currently - i am experimenting to see if dense keypoints characterise an image .